# Hide query string from url when user redirects to page

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using webflow to host my site. In the redirection section on the hosting tab. I added a 301 redirect query string that redirects to my index, I do this because I wanted to track where do the users come from in my site.

Read this article and try it out:
https://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/how-to-track-landing-page-redirects-using-google-analytics

So basically it states this:

- old path: /mexico
- new path: example.com/?key=mexico

So for example i created a redirect /mexico to go to my index with a query string. Currently it works really well, but i want to know if it is possible that the user does not see the query string when entering from a redirect link.

For example when user enters by example.com/mexico, the url search bar shows only example.com

I tried hiding it using javascript, but does not work.

```
    var testURL = 'myurl';
    testURL.split('?')[0];
```

Any clue? or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is with the [history API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/) - not available in older browsers.

The standard way of doing this is

```
history.pushState("object or state to represent your page", "page title", "/thenewurlpath");
```

You could add this to your `document.ready` callback, E.G.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  history.pushState("something", "newtitle", "/thenewpath");
  // Whatever else your document.ready callback is doing...
})
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: thank you! And this will still work for my Analytics?

Comment: I do not know.

I found this article online.

https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/03/30/single-page-applications-google-analytics/